# Sequencing futures to avoid race condition

Tags: scala

In this example I have a race condition, the string `s` at the end of the program should print with `@` and `#` replaced:

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  var s = "THIS IS A STRING"

  val f0 = Future { 0 }
  val f1 = Future { 1 }
  val fx = Seq(f0,f1)

  fx.map { 
    seq => seq.map {  i =>
          println("BEFORE ---> " + s)
          if (i == 0)
              s = s.replace ( "T", "@")
          else
              s = s.replace ("I", "#")
          println("AFTER ---> " + s)
        }
  }


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

But the code prints

```
BEFORE ---> THIS IS A STRING
BEFORE ---> THIS IS A STRING
AFTER ---> TH#S #S A STR#NG
AFTER ---> TH#S #S A STR#NG
```

How to avoid this race condition? how to change the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sure way to avoid race conditions is to not have mutable state. 
Something like this would work:

```
 val s = "THIS IS A STRING"
 Future
   .sequence(Seq(Future(0), Future(1)))
   .map { 
      _.foldLeft(s) {
        case (s, 0) => s.replaceAll("T", "@")
        case (s, _) => s.replaceAll("I", "#")
     }
   }.andThen { 
     case Success(str) => println("RESULT: " + str)
   }
```